# C# How to change console cursor shape?

Tags: c#, .net, console, cursor

I'm writing a simple console application, but I don't like the shape of the cursor used in the console.
I would like to change it to a vertical line as I did through the command line settings, but after using the

```
Console.ShowVisible = true;
```

it changes to the standard underscore.

I tried to find the solution on this site but didn't find.

Comment: This is changed in the console window properties, not in code.

Answer (score -2):

This is from Price Mark.Js book about C# 10 and .ENet6
Setting options with arguments
We will now use these arguments to allow the user to pick a color for the background,
foreground, and cursor size of the output window. The cursor size can be an integer value from
1, meaning a line at the bottom of the cursor cell, up to 100, meaning a percentage of the height
of the cursor cell.
The System namespace is already imported so that the compiler knows about the ConsoleColor
and Enum types:

1. Add statements to warn the user if they do not enter three arguments and then parse
   those arguments and use them to set the color and dimensions of the console window,
   as shown in the following code:

```
if (args.Length < 3)
{
    WriteLine("You must specify two colors and cursor size, e.g.");
    WriteLine("dotnet run red yellow 50");
    return; // stop running
}
ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(
         enumType: typeof(ConsoleColor),
         value: args[0],
         ignoreCase: true);
BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(
         enumType: typeof(ConsoleColor),
         value: args[1],
         ignoreCase: true);
CursorSize = int.Parse(args[2]);
```

Setting the CursorSize is only supported on Windows.

2. In Visual Studio, navigate to Project | Arguments Properties, and change the
   arguments to: red yellow 50, run the console app, and note the cursor is half the size
   and the colors have changed in the window, as shown in Figure 2.7:

3.In Visual Studio Code, run the code with arguments to set the foreground color to red,
the background color to yellow, and the cursor size to 50%, as shown in the following
command:

dotnet run red yellow 5

Although the compiler did not give an error or warning, at runtime some API calls may fail on
some platforms. Although a console application running on Windows can change its cursor
size, on macOS, it cannot, and complains if you try.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original poster's question at all. The OP is asking how to change the shape of the cursor, and - as they have observed - making the cursor visible programatically changes the shape back to the console default shape.